# how to resize the PVC with helm

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

Please help me understand how to change the pvc value in redis HA cluster...

my value.yaml:

```
auth:
  enabled: false

metrics:
  enabled: true

master:
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    size: 1Gi

slave:
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    size: 1Gi

sentinel:
  enabled: true
  downAfterMilliseconds: 600
  automateClusterRecovery: true
```

after command:
`helm install redis-sentinel bitnami/redis --values values.yaml -n redis`

I get a disk size of 8GB:

```
NAME                               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
redis-data-redis-sentinel-node-0   Bound    pvc-933f75c2-3290-4921-949d-5c2c3894b6a9   8Gi        RWO            standard       5m16s
redis-data-redis-sentinel-node-1   Bound    pvc-96d1ca03-aa6d-445b-bab9-f8ea1bef53a2   8Gi        RWO            standard       4m52s
redis-data-redis-sentinel-node-2   Bound    pvc-192063f2-e20e-4acd-82ef-3215610a19d1   8Gi        RWO            standard       4m25s
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on this file and the documentation https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/redis/values.yaml you need to pass or change the parameter `master.persistence.size` and `replica.persistence.size`(default value 8Gi) https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis/#parameters

Comment: So I did...look closely

Comment: Yeah, it should be replica instead of slave, look closely 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the [default values of the bitnami/redis chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis?modal=values)

- slave: has been renamed to replica
- sentinel is missing a persistence.enabled: false

try the following as values.yaml:

```
auth:
  enabled: false

metrics:
  enabled: true
replica:
  persistence:
    size: 1Gi

sentinel:
  enabled: true
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    size: 1Gi
  downAfterMilliseconds: 600
  automateClusterRecovery: true
```

```
❯ k get pvc -n redis
NAME                                  STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
redis-data-redis-sentinel-node-0      Bound    pvc-e781f569-0b60-4197-8cba-5c72fbc759e4   1Gi        RWO            standard       21s
sentinel-data-redis-sentinel-node-0   Bound    pvc-08b8c4fe-fe93-4a41-9f62-9062c54cb7e7   1Gi        RWO            standard       21s
```

Comment: This config does not create pvc :(

Comment: @cevoye I think i missunderstood you if you only want to set the size you can set it via replica.persistence i ve updated the answer